# ng-click $event not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: angularjs

I was checking the angular doc for ng-click and I found a strange bug in firefox

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-

The example given in the above link is working in chrome and opera, but it is not showing me $event properties in Mozilla firefox. The version i m using is 33.0.

Please let me know if there is an alternative to user event attribute in Mozilla firefox

Comment: What is actually printed when you click the button?

Comment: Maybe the p issn't in the scope of the click event. The event attribute works in firefox too. You can see if you take a look to your console. In the example console.log(clickEvent); print the event to your console and it works.

Comment: Perhaps [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101492/automatically-pass-event-with-ng-click)'s answer can help you..

Comment: Seems to be working fine now in Firefox 37.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the angularjs version is 1.5 which is not release yet.

Try to use the angularjs 1.4.8 version.