# get parent div id onclick of icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

On click of fa-eye icon I want to focus/highlight only that div.

Html:

```
<i style="float: right; margin: 8px; cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-eye" ng-click="focus()"></i>
```

JS:

```
$scope.focus = function($element) {
        $('#focus-overlay').toggleClass("focus-overlay");
        $('#last').toggleClass("widget-focus-enabled");
      };
```

In place of `id="last"` I have to find the id on click of icon and then need to add class..

I tried : `$($event.target).parent()` but not able to get the result.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/HvTRdjNVdmHjnyG41O4F?p=preview

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `$event` property of `angularjs` in `ng-click` method.

```
ng-click="focus($event)"
```

**In your method do so.**

```
    $scope.focus = function($element) {
        var parent= $($element.target).closest("div");
        $('#focus-overlay').toggleClass("focus-overlay");
        $('#last').toggleClass("widget-focus-enabled");
      };
```

Comment: I am doing .. var parent= $($element.target).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent(); then I am getting the result is it correct practise ?

Comment: i think you should pass a id into the directive wherever you are using directive and using that you can collapse the div. it would be better solution

Comment: I don't have id reference.. that's why I am finding on click.. any other solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` for getting the current object,

```
ng-click="focus(this)"
```

Then in the function,

```
$scope.focus = function($element) {
        var parent= $($element).closest("div");
        $('#focus-overlay').toggleClass("focus-overlay");
        $('#last').toggleClass("widget-focus-enabled");
      };
```

`.closest("div")` will get the parent div. Advantage of `closest()` over `parent()` is it can traverse multiple level.

Comment: this will not give you current element it will give the scope of the element

Comment: I dont want closest() I want parent().parent() Is it correct if i will do.. $($element.target).parent().closest("div");

Comment: @ngLover 'this will not give you current element' ? what do you meant by that?

Comment: using this keyword, you can not get the element in the focus method

Comment: which element you are mentioning about? this will be 'fa-eye' element in this context

Comment: Oh i see you have not passed $element in link method, ok will work then

Answer (score 1):

if you read this thread:

[Automatically pass $event with ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101492/automatically-pass-event-with-ng-click)

you will see the comment by  zeroflagL, which i just upvoted,
you are trying to modify a visual component in a controller,
which is not what is the intention of this handler

it is further supported by the angular documentation:
'Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. '
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

there is nothing stopping you from using plain old javascript here

i have added a script block that applies a style, not to the direct
parent but a few up

here is your modified plunker,

http://plnkr.co/edit/0x4ZqKoQcQLHXMMWtLJD

but in essence here are the additions:

index.html:

```
<script>
var _handleclick = function(ele) {
ele.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
</script>
```

template.html:

```
<i style="float: right; margin: 8px; cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-eye" onclick="_handleclick(this)" ng-click="focus()"></i>
```